# PEG grammar to parse optional content

Tags: ruby, treetop, peg

Can anyone tell me how to write syntax on [Treetop](http://treetop.rubyforge.org/) that supports both:

```
system u AAA1 car=5, motor=4
```

and

```
system u car=5, motor=4
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use an "Optional Expression" (see about 60% down on [this page](http://treetop.rubyforge.org/syntactic_recognition.html)):

```
grammar Sokmesa
  rule line
    "system" wsp+ marker wsp+ (category wsp+)? attributelist
  end
  rule category
    "AAA1" # Or whatever
  end
  # Add rules for 'marker', 'wsp', and 'attributelist' here
end
```